# Javascript HTML escaping but preserving linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a small jQuery script to help me build a styleguide. The script is used to copy and escape a piece of HTML and print it as documentation. My problem, however, is preversing linebreaks in the html. I would love for my escaped HTML to be formatted just like I have typed it. How is that possible?

```
$('.documentation-element').each(function() {
  var HTML = $(this).html();
  $(this).next().find('code').text(HTML).html();
});
```

See full example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tolborg/nr7fs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a  `<code>` tag, but that doesn't preserve line breaks. You need a `<pre>` tag for that. So wrap your `<code>` tag inside a `<pre>` tag and your code should work as is - except you don't need the extra `.html()` at the end (it doesn't hurt anything, it just doesn't *do* anything):

```
$('.documentation-element').each(function() {
    var HTML = $(this).html();
    $(this).next().find('code').text(HTML);
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr7fs/7/).

You may also want to tweak the leading whitespace on each line, but what you want there will depend on the output you want.

For example, [here's a version that strips leading whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/nr7fs/8/) and also removes the extra newlines at the beginning and end:

```
$('.documentation-element').each(function() {
    var HTML = $(this).html().trim().replace( /\n\s+/, '\n' );
    $(this).next().find('code').text(HTML);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `text()` method to `html()`:

```
$(this).next().find('code').html(HTML);
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/nr7fs/2/)

Comment: But that doesn't display the escaped HTML in the output page, it displays the rendered HTML.